# Convert UUID to bytes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to take a `uuid` and convert it back into the bytes it was generated from.

I've been studying the `SecureRandom` source to see if I can reverse engineer the UUID back into bytes, but I'm having a hard time with it.

What I need to do is basically the inverse of this:

```
def self.uuid
  ary = self.random_bytes(16).unpack("NnnnnN")
  ary[2] = (ary[2] & 0x0fff) | 0x4000
  ary[3] = (ary[3] & 0x3fff) | 0x8000
  "%08x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%08x" % ary
end
```

So I have this uuid:

```
"4b6d2066-78ac-49db-b8c4-9f58d8e8842f"
```

Which started out as this string of bytes:

```
"Km fx\xAC\xC9\xDB\xF8\xC4\x9FX\xD8\xE8\x84/"
```

Which was this unpacked:

```
[
    [0] 1265442918,
    [1] 30892,
    [2] 51675,
    [3] 63684,
    [4] 40792,
    [5] 3639116847
]
```

And this after `ary[2]` and `ary[3]` where modified

```
[
    [0] 1265442918,
    [1] 30892,
    [2] 18907,
    [3] 47300,
    [4] 40792,
    [5] 3639116847
]
```

So I got the original uuid split back out into its unjoined parts:

```
[
    [0] "4b6d2066",
    [1] "78ac",
    [2] "49db",
    [3] "b8c4",
    [4] "9f58",
    [5] "d8e8842f"
]
```

The problem I'm having is I'm not sure what the inverse of these 2 lines are:

```
ary[2] = (ary[2] & 0x0fff) | 0x4000
ary[3] = (ary[3] & 0x3fff) | 0x8000
```

And I'm also not sure how to turn the remaining elements back into their integer values.  I'm sure it is some form of `pack` or `unpack`, but I'm not sure what it needs.

Comment: Bitwise `OR` (as well as `AND`) is not revertable, though. Look: `ruby -e 'puts "#{0x4000 | 0x4000} vs. #{0x0000 | 0x4000}"' # ⇒ 16384 vs. 16384`.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem I'm having is I'm not sure what the inverse of these 2 lines are:
>
> ```
> ary[2] = (ary[2] & 0x0fff) | 0x4000
> ary[3] = (ary[3] & 0x3fff) | 0x8000
> ```

Those two lines aren't revertible… They're doing bit arithmetics to set the version and variant bits of a v4 (aka random) uuid, for RFC 4122 compliance.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

The numbers should correspond to:

```
byte & UUID_CLEAR_VER | UUID_VERSION_4 = byte & b'00001111' | b'01000000'
byte & UUID_CLEAR_VAR | UUID_VAR_RFC   = byte & b'00111111' | b'10000000'
```

As the above lines and the rfc might hint, what you really want isn't so much the uuid's bytes as is its bits, in order reverse-engineer its components. It really is a 128-bit integer, and the hex representation is basically passing the entire thing through bin2hex and reformatting it so it's reasonably readable.

Here's a variation of similar code in PHP, for reference:

https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/util/String.php#L55

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense.  The reason I was trying to reverse engineer a uuid was to see if 2 binary files I was trying to compare (which includes a uuid, and a calculation off of the uuid) were equal.  I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: this is a good explanation, but a code sample in Ruby was requested

Comment: @Tilo: To get the Ruby version, translate e.g. `b'00001111'` to `0b00001111`. (Feel free to edit the answer.) Also, I'm not sure where you're seeing Eugene ask for a code sample. He's asking what the two lines are about.