# Is a generated UUID from a String reversible?

Tags: java, security, uuid

If I generate a UUID from a "seed" string as follows, is there any way for someone to re-generate the original string?

```
UUID uuid = null;
    try {
        uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(("seedString").getBytes("utf8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("UUID: " + uuid.toString());
```

I would assume it isn't possible, as I believe this person found here: [Convert UUID to bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409330/convert-uuid-to-bytes)

However, I see that the same UUID is generated every time from a certain String/bytes, and since it has to be unique, simple "seed" values could just be guessed? For example, UUID of f is 8fa14cdd-754f-31cc-a554-c9e71929cce7 so if I see that I know it was generated from "f".

Comment: Well the thing is even if UUIDs were reversible, UUIDs don't guarantee uniqueness. It is possible (although [extremely unlikely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates)) that two different things can have the same UUID generated for them. But to answer your question, no not really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are getting the UUID by casting bytes to a UUID, and you are always using the same starting bytes to cast from, the uuid would always be the same UUID across multiple runs.

I think you've confused a random seed with the "from bytes" method in the UUID routines.  It is more like a cast than a seed initialization.  And even if it was like a seed initialization, initializing with a constant seed would only mean that you always walk the "same" pseudo-random path (meaning that after walking it once, you can know the next step(s)).

`aug` also makes an excellent point, which I'll elaborate a bit on here.  A UUID is an identifier, which is assumed to be unique only by virtue of there being so many to choose from; however, if you create a routine that returns the same one(s) repeatedly, it's not going to be unique due to your selection mechanism.  The actual mechanism doesn't assure uniqueness; even less so when using a routine guaranteed to return identical values.

As they are not guaranteed to be unique (UUIDs have a fixed number of bits and eventually all combinations can be exhausted), one can imagine that there are more inputs than UUIDs (although there's a lot of UUIDs) so UUID collision is inevitable (even if it would theoretically take more time than the heat death of the universe).  From a practical side of things, you probably have little to worry about; but, it could still (minuscule chance) happen.

This also means that one can (in theory) guarantee that some two inputs out there can wind up with the same UUID, and as a result, UUIDs are not generally reversible (however, in specific (limited) cases, perhaps they could be made reversible).

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of strings that may generate a given UUID, so even if somebody guesses the string you used to create a given UUID, they may never be sure.

Comment: I thought UUIDs are always unique, how could multiple strings generate the same UUID?

Comment: @Flyview UUIDs are not always unique in the strictest sense of the world _always_.  They are practically unique, in the sense that you've probably won the lottery over a few billion times by the time you repeat a UUID using a decent generator.